# Blazor Validating - is there a way to validate specific fields on model but not all fields

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a form with 2 fields (Name and address) all both required field in my model.

On my model I have 5 properties, (ID (Pk), Name , Address, Createdby, and Updatedby), which are all set to required exceptthe primark key ID.

On my Editform I would like to allow just the Name and Address field to be populated, but the createdby and updatedby to be done in my Insert.

How do I get this to valid on my form. I'm getting not valid because of the required rule on the (Createdby and Updatedby) and this comes up when i add validationsummary tag. if i dont add the tag, the textboxes are valid, but the submitPerson method does not.

Is there a way to get by this? Please see my code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
****MY EDITFORM ********

  <EditForm EditContext="@myEditContext" OnSubmit="@SubmitPerson">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator /> 

                <InputText class="form-control" id="NameInput" @bind-Value="Person.Name" />   
                <InputText class="form-control" id="AddressInput" @bind-Value="Person.Address" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </EditForm>
```

```
*********** MY CODE ****************

@code { 

    public PersonModel Person = new PersonModel();
    EditContext myEditContext { get; set; }
    private string ValidMEssage; 

    protected override void OnInitialized() {

        myEditContext = new EditContext(Person);
        base.OnInitialized();

    }



// my submit button method

   protected void SubmitPerson(EditContext editContext) {

        bool isFormValid = editContext.Validate();

        if (isFormValid)
        {   
        //apply when the form is valid
        ValidMEssage = "Save successfully";

        }
        else 
    {
            //apply when the form is not valid
            ValidMEssage = "Invalid";

        }

}
```

```
*****MY MODEL ********

  public class PersonModel    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public String Address { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public String CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public String UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected.  You have a `PersonModel` and your model never satisfies the `[Required()]` attributes.

A couple options:

1. Initialize your model to be valid.

   ```
    @code { 

        public PersonModel Person = new PersonModel() 
                                       { 
                                           CreatedBy="NonEmpty", 
                                           UpdatedBy="NonEmpty" 
                                       }
   ```
2. Remove the constraints that your model is not satisfying.

public class PersonModel    {
public int ID { get; set; }

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public String Address { get; set; }

    public String CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public String UpdatedBy { get; set; }

}
```

3. Pick a possibly more appropriate Model for a "form with 2 fields"

   public class PersonModel
   {

   ```
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public String Address { get; set; }

    }
   ```